How are genetic hallmarks of aging somehow “reset” at conception?
I’m a layman and genuinely curious about this, so forgive me if I use the wrong terminology or obviously don’t know what I’m talking about. Regardless of whether parents have a child at 18 or at 40, the offspring still has the dna of a newborn at birth (in terms of dna age metrics like mutations/errors, methylation, and telomere length). Meanwhile, doesn’t conception and fertilization involve continuation and replication of genetic material from both parents? How is it, then, that information loss in the parent’s dna due to replication (which could arguably be what aging is) isn’t inherited or perpetuated across generations? How does the offspring get a "fresh" copy of dna? I assume sperm and egg cells age like any other cells in the body, right?

Welcome to SE Biology. As you say you are a layman, you will be aware from reading the [Tour] that yours is not the constituency for which this site is intended. The gist of your question is of interest, nevertheless, but the title betrays an unjustified assumption that is incorrect. There is no reset. So I would suggest it be redrafted in terms of the effect of aging and consequent mutations on DNA of the offspring. And please avoid irrelevant asides about the nature of aging. Finally, if you are unsure of an assumption you are making, please use the less didactic “Am I right in assuming…”

Hello, thank you but the assumption my question “betrays” actually had some basis in the peer-reviewed literature (see link below). Also, how is DNA methylation and telomere length “irrelevant” if these are the hallmarks of aging I’m asking about and are well accepted as associated with aging? The link to the paper that discusses rejuvenation at conception: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1471491420302173#:~:text=For%20example%2C%20on%20the%20basis,must%20be%20reset%20after%20conception.

There is no reset of the DNA itself. Any mutations in the DNA the gametes is fixed. The question of protein methylation is different and should be kept distinct. If your level of knowledge is such that you are sure something happens, I suggest that it should be easy to find for yourself, how.

Just write an answer explaining why something is wrong, in that case

NominalSystems, please keep your language civilized.

From a DNA perspective, consider that a lot of aging is stochastic. By the end of a human lifespan, it's likely that a couple of our trillions of cells have collected enough mutations to be cancerous or close to it, and that's all the whole organism needs to die of cancer eventually. A gamete is just one cell, though. "Bad" gametes that are highly damaged are unlikely to develop into a viable organism. Reproduction allows for selection of just one of the "good" cells. It isn't necessary for that selection to be "intentional" or directed, though: you just can't build a whole, functional organism with a cell that's too damaged. A skin cell, say, can do it's job just fine with a lot of damage to genes that aren't involved in the function of skin, but a whole brand new animal won't get very far.
For brain aging, part of the problem of aging is developmental. The nervous system develops through an intense choreography of guidance cues that map out the tracts that connect different brain regions and all of the sensorimotor and organ systems with the nervous system. A lot of that follows the growth of the organs and body itself; you don't grow arms first and then send neural axons down the already grown arm, the neurons that will sense and control the arm grow along with the vasculature as the arm itself grows. When a neuron dies, it's gone for good but it's not just that the information stored in the connections that neuron made are lost. There is no possible way for the longer range connections to ever be rebuilt because they depend on signalling that was only present at some moment in time. Starting from scratch will revisit all those developmental milestones.
It's also not perfect. Each gamete has maybe 20-50 mutations not found in the parent genome. Many have little effect, some might be bad, some might increase fitness. That variation drives future evolution.
(This is really just a draft: todos are to add references and discuss various ways gametes are protected from mutation like dividing early and sparsely and not doing a lot of work that accumulates oxidative stress)

But wouldn’t it be better to address the key point of what the state of the gametes is at fertilization, and emphasize that the assumption of a “reset” is incorrect. I know nothing of embryology and that sort of biology, but surely the gametes do not divide and undergo telomere shortening until fertilization, in contrast to the poster’s assumption. And isn’t there evidence that birth defects are more prevalent in the offspring of older parents? Please give us some concrete stuff rather than stochastics.

Then there is the question of methylation of chromosomal proteins and the different "imprinting" in sperm and ovum.

I realize this is only one paper, but see the highlights including “ We propose that the zygote–ground zero period is associated with rejuvenation, wherein the biological age is decreased, telomeres are extended, and molecular damage is cleared”. Link: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1471491420302173#:~:text=For%20example%2C%20on%20the%20basis,must%20be%20reset%20after%20conception.

@NominalSystems I think the telomeres are probably the most boring part of cellular aging and get way too much press for their value; telomeres are useful as a limit on unchecked replication to combat cancer. The limit is trivially reversed by telomerase. If you want to ask a more specific question about a specific paper, I'd recommend doing that directly rather than referring to it obliquely and then mentioning in a comment. I think papers like the one you reference are a bit misguided, though, and are more focused on an imaginative science of anti-aging than on understanding development.

Thanks, I only found the paper after posting the question though, but have heard this idea before. Any insights on the molecular damage portion and not just the telomeres? Also, I’m curious what you think makes the paper misguided? Is it wrong assumptions about biology? There are other papers arguing the same thing:  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8232908/. What about this seems unscientific besides elucidating mechanisms of “anti aging” which get mixed in with pseudoscience sometimes in other, non peer-reviewed settings?

@NominalSystems I think it's misguided because it imagines that gametes need to anti-age (and that it's possible to do so), which I do not think accurately describes the biology. Of course you'll find a lot of papers on this, because as people get old they want to not get old so there's a lot of money and excitement around anti-aging. Note also that this is the same author of these two papers. I don't know this specific work and I'm not saying it's wrong or unscientific, but I'd urge attention towards what they define as "aging" and consider whether that's actually what aging is.

I think most people would conceptualize "aging" as involving the irreversible changes that accumulate over a biological lifetime; their measure of aging here is an easily-reversible DNA modification.

Thank you for discussing it. Seems like your overarching point is there’s a lot more to it than a few easily manipulable attributes of dna
